# Copy selected data to a specific sheet using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to select particular columns and then paste this onto a particular sheet, if sheet exists then erase existing data and paste newly copied data. This should work in loop to be refreshed with new data entered in the main sheet.

My code creates the required sheet but pastes data into another new sheet.

```vb
Sub Datasort()
'The sheet with all the imported data columns must be active when this macro is run
Dim newSht As Worksheet, sSht As Worksheet, Hdrs As Variant, i As Long, Fnd As Range, Sheet_Name As String
Set sSht = Worksheets("all zip codes")
'Expand the array below to include all relevant column headers
Hdrs = Array("Country", "Zip codes", "GSS")
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Sheet_Name = "Dataformatted"

Set newSht = Worksheets.Add(after:=sSht)

With sSht.UsedRange.Rows(1)
    For i = LBound(Hdrs) To UBound(Hdrs)
        Set Fnd = .Find(Hdrs(i), lookat:=xlWhole)
        
        If Not Fnd Is Nothing Then
            Intersect(Fnd.EntireColumn, sSht.UsedRange).Copy
            newSht.Cells(1, i + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            newSht.Cells(1, i + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
        End If
    Next i
    
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End With

If (Sheet_Exists(Sheet_Name) = False) And (Sheet_Name <> "") Then
    Worksheets.Add(after:=sSht).Name = Sheet_Name
End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Function Sheet_Exists(WorkSheet_Name As String) As Boolean
Dim newSht As Worksheet
 
Sheet_Exists = False
 
For Each newSht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If newSht.Name = WorkSheet_Name Then
        Sheet_Exists = True
    End If
Next
 
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(not tested), but you're adding sheet everytime it runs, so assuming everything else works fine, you should:

replace Set newSht = Worksheets.Add(after:=sSht) with below

```vb
if not Sheet_Exists(Sheet_Name) then Worksheets.Add(after:=sSht).Name = Sheet_Name
Set newSht = Worksheets(Sheet_Name)
```

and remove the following part

```vb
If (Sheet_Exists(Sheet_Name) = False) And (Sheet_Name <> "") Then
    Worksheets.Add(after:=sSht).Name = Sheet_Name
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

### Copy Worksheet Columns

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Datasort()
    
    Const sName As String = "all zip codes"
    Const dName As String = "Dataformatted"
    Const dfcAddress As String = "A1"
    Dim Headers As Variant: Headers = VBA.Array("Country", "Zip codes", "GSS")
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.UsedRange
    Dim shrg As Range: Set shrg = srg.Rows(1)
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
        Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If dws Is Nothing Then
        Set dws = wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=sws)
        dws.Name = dName
    Else
        dws.UsedRange.Clear
    End If
    Dim dfCell As Range: Set dfCell = dws.Range(dfcAddress)
        
    Dim scrg As Range
    Dim hIndex As Variant
    Dim c As Long
    
    For c = 0 To UBound(Headers)
        hIndex = Application.Match(Headers(c), shrg, 0)
        If IsNumeric(hIndex) Then
            Set scrg = srg.Columns(hIndex)
            dfCell.Resize(scrg.Rows.Count).Value = scrg.Value
            dfCell.EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = scrg.EntireColumn.ColumnWidth
            Set dfCell = dfCell.Offset(, 1)
        End If
    Next c
            
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    MsgBox "Data formatted."

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! i see that your code is more streamlined and also works :) much appreciated for the answer

Comment: You're welcome. When you get enough reputation, make sure to come back and give it an upvote to prove it.

Comment: I already tried but definitely will do so! Thank you!